# How to test a controller POST method which returns no data in response content in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testing, integration-testing, xunit

i am new to integration tests. I have a controller method which adds a user to the database, as shown below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUserAsync([FromBody] CreateUserRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var command = new CreateUserCommand
        {
            Login = request.Login,
            Password = request.Password,
            FirstName = request.FirstName,
            LastName = request.LastName,
            MailAddress = request.MailAddress,
            TokenOwnerInformation = User
        };

        await CommandBus.SendAsync(command);

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        await HandleExceptionAsync(e);
                
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
            new {e.Message});
    }
}
```

As you have noticed my method returns no information about the user which has been added to the database - it informs about the results of handling a certain request using the status codes. I have written an integration test to check is it working properly:

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task ShouldCreateUser()
        {
            // Arrange
            var createUserRequest = new CreateUserRequest
            {
                Login = "testowyLogin",
                Password = "testoweHaslo",
                FirstName = "Aleksander",
                LastName = "Kowalski",
                MailAddress = "akowalski@onet.poczta.pl"
            };
            var serializedCreateUserRequest = SerializeObject(createUserRequest);
            
            // Act
            var response = await HttpClient.PostAsync(ApiRoutes.CreateUserAsyncRoute,
                serializedCreateUserRequest);
            
            // Assert
            response
                .StatusCode
                .Should()
                .Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

I am not sure is it enough to assert just a status code of response returned from the server. I am confused because, i don't know, shall i attach to assert section code, which would get all the users and check does it contain created user for example. I don't even have any id of such a user because my application finds a new id for the user while adding him/her to the database. I also have no idea how to test methods like that:

```
        [HttpGet("{userId:int}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserAsync([FromRoute] int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                var query = new GetUserQuery
                {
                    UserId = userId,
                    TokenOwnerInformation = User
                };
                
                var user = await QueryBus
                    .SendAsync<GetUserQuery, UserDto>(query);

                var result = user is null
                    ? (IActionResult) NotFound(new
                        {
                            Message = (string) _stringLocalizer[UserConstants.UserNotFoundMessageKey]
                        })
                    : Ok(user);

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(e);
                
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                    new {e.Message});
            }
        }
```

I believe i should somehow create a user firstly in Arrange section, get it's id and then use it in Act section with the GetUserAsync method called with the request sent by HttpClient. Again the same problem - no information about user is returned, after creation (by the way - it is not returned, because of my CQRS design in whole application - commands return no information). Could you please explain me how to write such a tests properly? Have i missed anything? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's easy: you *cannot* write an integration test that asserts beyond the HTTP200, it's the nature of an asynchronous application. If you do want more asserts, you'll need automation/end-to-end tests, where you create a random user and wait (retrying dynamically) until the system is able to create the user in an actual database. As an integration-layer test that can be run as part of a build, your code looks fine just asserting OK response

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
var response = (CreatedResult) await _controller.Post(createUserRequest);
response.StatusCode.Should().Be(StatusCodes.Status201Created);
```

The second line above is not necessary, just there for illustration.

Also, your response it's better when you return a 201 (Created) instead of the 200(OK) on Post verbs, like:

```
return Created($"api/users/{user.id}", user);
```

To test NotFound's:

```
var result = (NotFoundObjectResult) await _controller.Get(id);
result.StatusCode.Should().Be(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
```

The `NotFoundObjectResult` assumes you are returning something. If you are just responding with a 404 and no explanation, replace `NotFoundObjectResult` with a `NotFoundResult`.

And finally InternalServerErrors:

```
var result = (ObjectResult) await _controller.Get(id);
result.StatusCode.Should().Be(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [integrationFixture](https://github.com/ConnectingApps/DncWireMockDemo#integrationfixture) for that using this [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConnectingApps.IntegrationFixture/). This is an AutoFixture alternative for integration tests.

The documented examples use Get calls but you can do other calls too. Logically, you should test for the status code (`OkObjectResult` means 200) value and the response (which could be an empty string, that is no problem at all).

Here is the documented example for a normal Get call.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetTest()
{
    // arrange
    using (var fixture = new Fixture<Startup>())
    {
        using (var mockServer = fixture.FreezeServer("Google"))
        {
            SetupStableServer(mockServer, "Response");
            var controller = fixture.Create<SearchEngineController>();

            // act
            var response = await controller.GetNumberOfCharacters("Hoi");

            // assert
            var request = mockServer.LogEntries.Select(a => a.RequestMessage).Single();
            Assert.Contains("Hoi", request.RawQuery);
            Assert.Equal(8, ((OkObjectResult)response.Result).Value);
        }
    }
}

private void SetupStableServer(FluentMockServer fluentMockServer, string response)
{
    fluentMockServer.Given(Request.Create().UsingGet())
        .RespondWith(Response.Create().WithBody(response, encoding: Encoding.UTF8)
            .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK));
}
```

In the example above, the controller is resolved using the DI described in your `Startup` class.

You can also do an actual REST call using using [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#refit-the-automatic-type-safe-rest-library-for-net-core-xamarin-and-net). The application is self hosted inside your test.

```
using (var fixture = new RefitFixture<Startup, ISearchEngine>(RestService.For<ISearchEngine>))
{
    using (var mockServer = fixture.FreezeServer("Google"))
    {
        SetupStableServer(mockServer, "Response");
        var refitClient = fixture.GetRefitClient();
        var response = await refitClient.GetNumberOfCharacters("Hoi");
        await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync();
        var request = mockServer.LogEntries.Select(a => a.RequestMessage).Single();
        Assert.Contains("Hoi", request.RawQuery);
    }
}
```